# Getting nullpoint error when I try to insert values

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
public boolean addInfo(String username, String DOB, String gender, String password) {

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

            contentValues.put(UserProfile.Users.col_02, username);
            contentValues.put(UserProfile.Users.col_03, DOB);
            contentValues.put(UserProfile.Users.col_04, gender);
            contentValues.put(UserProfile.Users.col_05, password);

            long res = db.insert(UserProfile.Users.Table_Name, null, contentValues);

            if (res == -1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        }




public boolean updateInfo(String id, String username, String DOB, String gender, String password) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(UserProfile.Users.col_01, id);
        contentValues.put(UserProfile.Users.col_02, username);
        contentValues.put(UserProfile.Users.col_03, DOB);
        contentValues.put(UserProfile.Users.col_04, gender);
        contentValues.put(UserProfile.Users.col_05, password);

db.update(UserProfile.Users.Table_Name, contentValues, "ID = ?", new String[]{id});

        return true;

    }

    public Cursor readAllInfo(String id) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String[] projection = {
                UserProfile.Users.col_01,
                UserProfile.Users.col_02,
                UserProfile.Users.col_03,
                UserProfile.Users.col_04,
                UserProfile.Users.col_05
        };

        String selection = UserProfile.Users.col_01 + "=?";

        Cursor cursor = db.query(UserProfile.Users.Table_Name,
                projection,
                selection,
                new String[]{id},
                null,
                null,
                null);

        return cursor;

    }
  public Integer deleteInfo(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

  return db.delete(UserProfile.Users.Table_Name, "ID = ?", new String[]{id});

    }
```

These are my methods which I think nothing is wrong with the code, but still every time I call the `addInfo` method in my add button it says *"null point exception trying to invoke virtual method"*

Comment: Post your error log please

Answer (score 0):

The likely cause is that you are declaring but not instantiating the Database Helper object i.e. the **this**.

The methods are likely part of a class that extends SQliteOpenHelper and this will have a constructor, assuming the class is DBHelper then in the activity that invokes these methods

you would have something like

```
DBHelper myDatabaseHelper;
```

- Note that without the code that invokes (calls) the method then the actual names could be anything. The stack-trace, see [Debug your app - View the system log](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#systemLogView), also provides information that should be copied into such questions as it pinpoints where the exception happened.

before invoking the methods you need to instantiate (construct) myDatabaseHelper which would be something like :-

```
    myDatabaseHelper = new DBhelper(this); //<<<<<<<<<< You are likely missing this and hence myDatabaseHelper is null.
```

You could then use

```
     if (myDatabaseHelper.addInfo("TheUserName","2000-01-01","Female","thepassword"))
         ...... code to run if the info was added 
     { else {
         ... code to run if the user was not added
     }
```

As myDatabaseHelper is null the exception is raised when an attempt is made to access it (addInfo, if it were instantiated/constructed would be part of myDatabaseHelper)

Consider the following Example :-

Your DatabaseHelper (as will be used unchanged for both example runs) :-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE If NOT EXISTS " + UserProfile.Users.Table_Name +
                "(" +
                        UserProfile.Users.col_01 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                        UserProfile.Users.col_02 + " TEXT, " +
                        UserProfile.Users.col_03 + " TEXT," +
                        UserProfile.Users.col_04 + " TEXT," +
                        UserProfile.Users.col_05 + " TEXT" +
                ")"
        ); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public boolean addInfo(String username, String DOB, String gender, String password) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(UserProfile.Users.col_02, username);
        contentValues.put(UserProfile.Users.col_03, DOB);
        contentValues.put(UserProfile.Users.col_04, gender);
        contentValues.put(UserProfile.Users.col_05, password);
        long res = db.insert(UserProfile.Users.Table_Name, null, contentValues);
        if (res == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean updateInfo(String id, String username, String DOB, String gender, String password) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(UserProfile.Users.col_01, id);
        contentValues.put(UserProfile.Users.col_02, username);
        contentValues.put(UserProfile.Users.col_03, DOB);
        contentValues.put(UserProfile.Users.col_04, gender);
        contentValues.put(UserProfile.Users.col_05, password);
        db.update(UserProfile.Users.Table_Name, contentValues, "ID = ?", new String[]{id});
        return true;
    }

    public Cursor readAllInfo(String id) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] projection = {
                UserProfile.Users.col_01,
                UserProfile.Users.col_02,
                UserProfile.Users.col_03,
                UserProfile.Users.col_04,
                UserProfile.Users.col_05
        };

        String selection = UserProfile.Users.col_01 + "=?";

        Cursor cursor = db.query(UserProfile.Users.Table_Name,
                projection,
                selection,
                new String[]{id},
                null,
                null,
                null);
        return cursor;

    }
    public Integer deleteInfo(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(UserProfile.Users.Table_Name, "ID = ?", new String[]{id});
    }
}
```

- Notice that your code is embedded as is within the above.

And consider the invoking activity (WITHOUT instantiating myDatabasehelper) :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper myDatabaseHelper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //myDatabaseHelper = new DBHelper(this); //<<<<<<<<<< 
        myDatabaseHelper.addInfo("UserX","2000-01-01","Unknown","password");
        Cursor csr = myDatabaseHelper.readAllInfo("1");
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
    }
}
```

The you get the Null Pointer Exception (NPE) as per :-

```
2019-06-06 15:34:46.235 5658-5658/aso.so5647108356471083 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: aso.so5647108356471083, PID: 5658
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{aso.so5647108356471083/aso.so5647108356471083.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean aso.so5647108356471083.DBHelper.addInfo(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean aso.so5647108356471083.DBHelper.addInfo(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at aso.so5647108356471083.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

The following line being the pertintent line that explains that the variable that has been declared as being a DBhelper is null.

**`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean aso.so5647108356471083.DBHelper.addInfo(java.lang.String,java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`**

A simple change (uncommenting the line `myDatabaseHelper = new DBHelper(this);`) and using :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper myDatabaseHelper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDatabaseHelper = new DBHelper(this); //<<<<<<<<<<
        myDatabaseHelper.addInfo("UserX","2000-01-01","Unknown","password");
        Cursor csr = myDatabaseHelper.readAllInfo("1");
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
    }
}
```

works, extracting the added data and writing it to the log as per :-

```
2019-06-06 15:47:22.579 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@791f7af
2019-06-06 15:47:22.580 I/System.out: 0 {
2019-06-06 15:47:22.580 I/System.out:    _id=1
2019-06-06 15:47:22.580 I/System.out:    col02=UserX
2019-06-06 15:47:22.580 I/System.out:    col03=2000-01-01
2019-06-06 15:47:22.580 I/System.out:    col04=Unknown
2019-06-06 15:47:22.580 I/System.out:    col05=password
2019-06-06 15:47:22.580 I/System.out: }
2019-06-06 15:47:22.580 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, here myDatabaseHelper is object of your that class where you create tables.

```
myDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase().insert(UserProfile.Users.Table_Name, null, contentValues);
```